# Modifying an object based on a path

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to modify an object dynamically based on a path. But I am having some trouble. I have the below method that gets me the value at a path but now I need to modify a value at a path. The path length should not matter either so `prop.prop.prop.prop` should be okay. For example

```
let dataObj = {
  name: 'Old Name',
  address: {
    state: 'CA',
    timezone: 'America/California'
  }
}

let modifiedValues = {
  'name': 'New Name'
  'address.state': 'FL',
  'address.timezone': 'America/New_York'
}
```

I want to be able to loop over the second object and use the key and value to modify the first object or create a new object that follows that structure. That way I get an object that looks like below:

```
let dataObj = {
  name: 'New Name',
  address: {
    state: 'FL',
    timezone: 'America/New_York'
  }
}
```

Here is the method I have that will get me the value based on a path for reference:

```
getAttributeFromPath(path: string, entity: any): any {
  return path.split('.').reduce((a, b) => a && a[b], entity);
}
```

Comment: Were any of these answers helpful? How's about giving someone credit for their effort in helping you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a version of `getAttributeFromPath` to set an attribute from a path, and then use this to modify the first object.

Below I created a version (`setAttributeFromPath`) using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
let dataObj = {
  name: 'Old Name',
  address: {
    state: 'CA',
    timezone: 'America/California'
  }
};

let modifiedValues = {
  'name': 'New Name',
  'address.state': 'FL',
  'address.timezone': 'America/New_York'
};

const setAttributeFromPath = (path, entity, value) => {
  const pathParts = path.split('.');
  let obj = entity;
  
  pathParts.forEach((part, index) => {
    if (obj[part]) {
      if (index < pathParts.length - 1) {
        obj = obj[part];
      } else {
        obj[part] = value;
      }
    }
  });
};

Object.entries(modifiedValues).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  setAttributeFromPath(key, dataObj, value);
});

console.log(dataObj);
```

You can try to come up with a nice one-liner version of `setAttributeFromPath` which uses `reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through your items and check each for a dotted value. Then build a new object with the new structure:

```
let modifiedValues = {
    'name': 'New Name',
    'address.state': 'FL',
    'address.timezone': 'America/New_York'
};

let newValues = {};
for(let item in modifiedValues){
    if(item.includes('.')){
        let splited = item.split('.');
        if(splited[0] in newValues)
            newValues[splited[0]][splited[1]] = modifiedValues[item];
        else{
            newValues[splited[0]] = {};
            newValues[splited[0]][splited[1]] = modifiedValues[item];
        }
    }else{
        newValues[item] = modifiedValues[item];
    }
}
console.log(newValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `eval` function here. The only thing you need to iterate over is your modified values, then simply set them.

```
let dataObj = {
  name: 'Old Name',
  address: {
    state: 'CA',
    timezone: 'America/California'
  }
}

let modifiedValues = {
  'name': 'New Name',
  'address.state': 'FL',
  'address.timezone': 'America/New_York'
}

function updateObject(values, obj){
    Object.keys(values).forEach( key=> {
        eval(`obj.${key} = values[key]`);
    });
}

updateObject(modifiedValues, dataObj);
console.log(dataObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much more concise and efficient take on such a function based on popping off the last value and using that to assign the correct reference to the new value:

```js
let dataObj = {
  name: 'Old Name',
  address: {
    state: 'CA',
    timezone: 'America/California'
  }
}

let modifiedValues = {
  'name': 'New Name',
  'address.state': 'FL',
  'address.timezone': 'America/New_York'
}

function setAttributeFromPath(path, entity, value) {
  const final = (path = path.split('.')).pop();
  path.reduce((a, b) => a && a[b], entity)[final] = value;
}

for(const key in modifiedValues) setAttributeFromPath(key, dataObj, modifiedValues[key]);

console.log(dataObj);
```

The loop can be combined into the function with something like this, using array destructuring:

```
function setAttributesFromPath(pathMap, entity) {
  Object.entries(pathMap).forEach(([path,value]) => {
    const final = (path = path.split('.')).pop();
    path.reduce((a, b) => a && a[b], entity)[final] = value;
  });
}
```